# News system CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I try add example from `http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html`

to my site, this is code:

news_model

```
<?php
class News_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }


public function get_news($art = FALSE)
{
    if ($art === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('news');
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('art' => $art));
    return $query->row_array();
}

public function set_news()
{
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'), 'dash', TRUE);

    $data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'art' => $art,
        'text' => $this->input->post('text'),
        'image'=> $image
    );

    return $this->db->insert('news', $data);
  }
}
?>
```

news_controller

```
<?php
class News extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('news_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
        $data['errors_login'] = array();
        $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
        $data['title'] = 'News archive';

    $this->load->view('main/open_news', $data);
    }

    public function view($art) {
    $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($art);

    if (empty($data['news_item']))
    {
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];
    $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
    $data['errors_login'] = array();
    $this->load->view('main/open_one_news', $data);
    }   
}
```

open_news

```
<?php
$this->load->view('mains/header');
$this->load->view('main/news');
$this->load->view('mains/footer');
?>
```

news view

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

    <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
    <div id="main">
        <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
    </div>
    <a href="news/<?php $news_item['art'] ?>">View article</a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

And when I click in `<a href="news/<?php $news_item['art'] ?>">View article</a>`

The page is not forwarding to concret page with news, only in link duplicate "news":

```
http://localhost/index.php/news/news/news/news/news/news
```

I dont know what is problem. But I think it will by may in routes.config
Because I have only:
`$route['default_controller'] = 'login';` -> this is my start page

But in CodeIgniter tutorial is:

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
```

But when I add some from 3 first line, even the first page with list of news doesn`t open.

SOLVED:
I make stupid mistake. Because controller name news, but function:  public function `view($art)`, and the link should be: `'news/view/'.$news_item['art']`.

Comment: Well, firstly you forgot the `echo` at `<a href="news/<?php $news_item['art'] ?>">View article</a>`, instead of `<a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['art'] ?>">View article</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `echo` at:

```
<a href="news/<?php $news_item['art'] ?>">View article</a>
```

You should use:

```
<a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['art'] ?>">View article</a>
```

or:

```
<?php echo anchor('news/' . $news_item['art'], 'View article');
```

or:

```
<?php echo anchor("news/{$news_item['art']}", 'View article');
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem with the below link

```
 <a href="news/<?php $news_item['art'] ?>">View article</a>
```

use codeigniter anchor instead

```
anchor('news/'.$news_item['art'],'View article');
```

try this and feed me back

Comment: This was good idea. I add:                                          `<?php echo anchor('news/'.$news_item['art'],'View article','class="link class"')?>`                                  And when I click in link (link is good), but I have error:`Page not found 404`

Comment: Thanks is everything ok! I make stupid mistake. Because controller name news, but function:  public function `view($art)`, and the link should be: `'news/view/'.$news_item['art']`. Thanks form help and plus for you! Thanks